# Is there a way to apply CSS styles between two siblings?

Tags: html, css

To give my question some context, I have 12 sibling divs that each represent a month of the year. Either 0, 1, or 2 of these divs can be selected at a given time. When selected, a class of "active" is applied to that div. When two divs are selected I would like to apply a style to all divs between the two selected.

eg.

```html
<div class="month">Jan</div>
<div class="month active">Feb</div>
<div class="month">Mar</div>
<div class="month">Apr</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">Jun</div>
<div class="month active">Jul</div>
<div class="month">Aug</div>
<div class="month">Sep</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>
<div class="month">Nov</div>
<div class="month">Dec</div>
```

So in the above snippet, I would like to apply a CSS style to the active months, as well as all months in-between. Is this possible in CSS, or am I better off with JS?

EDIT:

This doesn't work, but I think it might be on the right track.

```
.month.active ~ .month {
    background-color: $color-lighter-text;
    color: #fff;
}

.month.active:nth-child(2) ~ .month {
    background-color: #fff !important;
    color: $color-muted-text !important;
}
```

Comment: I would do is with jQuery.. Select all elements with month, find active, use each loop until next active and add classes to each element until you reach next active element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could select all the `.month` elements following the first `.active` element, and then override that styling by selecting all the `.month` elements that follow the second `.active` element:

```css
.month.active ~ .month,
.active {
  color: #f00;
}
.month.active ~ .month.active ~ .month {
  color: initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="month">Jan</div>
<div class="month active">Feb</div>
<div class="month">Mar</div>
<div class="month">Apr</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">Jun</div>
<div class="month active">Jul</div>
<div class="month">Aug</div>
<div class="month">Sep</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>
<div class="month">Nov</div>
<div class="month">Dec</div>
```

However, if you want a cleaner solution, I'd suggest using JS and adding an `.active` class to all the elements that you want to target.

If you're using jQuery, you can simply use the [`.nextUntil()` method](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/):

```
$('.month.active:first').nextUntil('.active').addClass('active');
```

```js
$('.month.active:first').nextUntil('.active').addClass('active');
```

```css
.month.active {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="month">Jan</div>
<div class="month active">Feb</div>
<div class="month">Mar</div>
<div class="month">Apr</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">Jun</div>
<div class="month active">Jul</div>
<div class="month">Aug</div>
<div class="month">Sep</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>
<div class="month">Nov</div>
<div class="month">Dec</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use general sibling selectors: `~`

```
<div class="month">Jan</div>
<div class="month active">Feb</div>
<div class="month">Mar</div>
<div class="month">Apr</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">Jun</div>
<div class="month active">Jul</div>
<div class="month">Aug</div>
<div class="month">Sep</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>
<div class="month">Nov</div>
<div class="month">Dec</div>

.month {background: red;}
.month.active {background: blue;}
.month.active ~ .month {background: blue;}
.month.active ~ .month.active ~ .month {background: red;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because of the cascading nature of CSS, the element before the `.active` cannot be effectively targeted from `.active's` reference. I added a `.prev` class to the element before an `.active`, then used the adjacent sibling selector `+` when referencing `.active` to the element after it.

My bad, you wanted the months in between so that can be done with the more indiscriminate `~`. Updated to reflect OP's request but probably the same solution as some before me, sorry :-\

```css
.month.active { 
  background-color: orange;
  }
.month.active ~ .month {
  background-color: orange;
}
.month.active ~ .month.active ~ .month {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="month">Jan</div>
<div class="month active">Feb</div>
<div class="month">Mar</div>
<div class="month">Apr</div>
<div class="month">May</div>
<div class="month">Jun</div>
<div class="month active">Jul</div>
<div class="month">Aug</div>
<div class="month">Sep</div>
<div class="month">Oct</div>
<div class="month">Nov</div>
<div class="month">Dec</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to target only the sibilings between the two `.active`, without having to indicate `background-color: initial;` for the sibilings after the second `.active`.

Note that if only one sibiling has the `.active` class, all the sibilings after that will be matched.

```
.month.active, 
.month.active ~ .month:not(.month.active ~ .month.active ~ .month) { 
  background-color: orange;
}
```

https://codepen.io/xmorelll/pen/wvdmbYq